Can't we use noCursorTimeout for timeseries collection?
I am using MongoDB cursor to find documents in my spring boot application as follows:
Criteria matchCriteria = new Criteria("timestamp").lt(100);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor =
        mongoTemplate
            .getCollection("collectionName")
            .find(new Query(matchCriteria).getQueryObject())
            .sort(ascending("sortField"))
            .limit(10000)
            .noCursorTimeout(true)
            .batchSize(10000)
            .allowDiskUse(true)
            .cursor();

It seems that this works fine if collectionName is regular MongoDB collection, but if the collection is Time Series collection I am getting error:
Command failed with error 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Option noCursorTimeout not supported in aggregation.

If I remove  .noCursorTimeout(true), this works fine. Why is it so? Any workaround so that I can include noCursorTimeout for Time Series collection as well?

try replacing noCursorTimeout with maxTimeMS. As far as I'm aware when you query a time series collection, the query gets converted to an aggregation pipeline which doesn't support noCursorTimeout.
